If the probabilities of two events add up to 1, must they be mutually exclusive?
I've been wondering: if the probability of the union of two events is $1,$ must the events be mutually exclusive? The answer is now perfectly clear after I came up with this counterexample: tossing a fair die, let A be the event "you throw greater than 1" and B the event "you throw less than 6".
What if the probabilities of two events add up to $1;$ are the events now necessarily mutually exclusive?

Roll a dice. How about you look at the probability of getting an even number and probability of getting a number more than 3?

The probability of these events don't add up to 1, you are leaving out the 1, so I don't see how this answers my question

What do you mean? The first ecent has probability $1/2$ and so does the second. But these are not exclusive.

Tossing a fair die, let $A$ be the event "you throw greater than $1$" and $B$ the event "you throw less than $6$".

Should say:  your phrasing is poor and that is causing confusion.  I am taking your question to mean "suppose the union of two events has probability $1$, does that mean the events are mutually exclusive?"  For which the answer is Obviously Not.  Others are reading your question as "suppose the probabilities of two events sum to $1$, must they be mutually exclusive?" For which the answer is, again, Obviously Not.

Please edit your post for clarity.  As I say, there are (at least) two interpretations for your question. Your header clearly asks whether, if the probabilities of two events sums to $1$, the events must be mutually exclusive.  The body of the question appears to be referring to the union of the two events, which is different (the probability of the union is generally not the sum of the probabilities).  Please edit for clarity.

Thanks, I modified my header because I was thinking about the probability of the union. But could you elaborate on this? "the probability of the union is generally not the sum of the probabilities"

What do you know about the inclusion-exlusion principle? Should answer your question about "the probability of the union is generally not the sum of the probabilities"

In general, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.  Thus, the probability of the union equals the sum of the probabilities only when the intersection has probability $0$.  If you look at my example, with the fair die, $P(A)=P(B)=\frac 56$, $P(A\cup B)=1$, and $P(A\cap B)=\frac 46$

"the probability of the union is generally not the sum of the probabilities" -- You should already know plenty of examples of this. In fact, every failed attempt to answer your question is an example.

Thanks, now it's perfectly clear. Thus the answer that I was looking for is:
Tossing a fair die, let A be the event "you throw greater than 1 " and B the event "you throw less than 6 ".

Your counterexample: tossing a fair die, let A be the event "you throw greater than 1" and B the event "you throw less than 6" does not work, as  the probabilities are $\frac56$ and $\frac56$ which add up to more than $1$.  But a fair die with $A$ being a prime number i.e. ${2,3,5}$ and $B$ being an even number  ${2,4,6}$ might be a counterexample.

No.  Take the equal distribution on $[0,1]$ and the events $X\le1/2$ and $X\ge1/2$.

Given that these four outcomes are equally probable, we have that $P(A)+P(B)=1.$


Two events $( E_1 )$ and $( E_2 )$ are mutually exclusive if and only if
$$P(E_1 \cap E_2) = 0$$
Now you say $$ P(E_1) + P(E_2) = 1 $$ then it can be expressed as:
$$
P(E_1) + P(E_2) = P(E_1 \cap E_2) + P(E_1 \cup E_2) = 1$$
Thus,
$$
P(E_1 \cap E_2)  = 1 -  P(E_1 \cup E_2)
$$
Can you say $P(E_1 \cap E_2) = 0 $ from this without any extra information?
Better would be to say two events are mutually exlusive if and only if $$
P(E_1) + P(E_2) = P(E_1 \cup E_2)$$
Probability sum = 1 has nothing to do with exclusiveness, getting a 1 on a die and getting a 2 on the same die on the same trial are mututally exclusive because they can't happen at the same time but their probability doesn't sum to 1.
And comment 1 below the question is a perfect example of events not being mutually exlusive even if they their probabilities add up to 1
